# How to plot a new graph in a old window in matplotlib of python

Tags: python, matplotlib, animation

I am doing a script without using animate because you can only use local variables and I need a way to replace a old graph in a window with a new one.

(Sorry i just begin using stack so sorry if this is javascript not python)

```py
while t < 10.0:

    utemp = np.zeros(Nx)
    plt.show()
    # It only shows at the end
    plt.plot(u)
    # Putting it here just plots another graph and does not replace

    for i in range(1, Nx - 1):
        utemp[i] = u[i] + c * dt / dx * (u[i + 1] - u[i - 1])


    u = utemp
    t += dt

# Plot the final waveform
plt.plot(u)
plt.show()
```

I tried to put plt.show in the body but it only shows at the end.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple animation hack example for matplotlib:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


for i in range(10):
    plt.figure()
    plt.scatter(i, i)
    plt.xlim([0, 10])
    plt.ylim([0, 10])
    plt.show(block=False)
    plt.pause(1)
```

Comment: Oh actually i found a way to import global variables but anyway i'll test yours

Comment: sorry this code just cascades a lot of plt windows

Comment: do you think i should close this question since i know how to use global variables in animation

Comment: Huh... might be specific to plotting device/OS... works on my machine... sorry it didn't work for yours.